# GTK on Windows Engines & Theme help

Tags: c, gtk

I have been trying to learn about GTK engines and themes. I have looked around for tutorials on how to use under windows, but for some reason I don't understand. I have read these to help as guidlines:

orford.org/gtk/

live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes

www.gtk.org/~otaylor/gtk/2.0/theme-engines.html

I do not understand what to do with the engines and the gtkrc file that I have grabbed from examples. I have read that I am supposed to download themes & engines from [Alexander Shaduri's gtk-win project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-win/files/GTK+%20Themes%20Package/2009-09-07/gtk2-themes-2009-09-07-win32_bin.zip/download), and copy the engine dll to "\GTK\lib\gtk-2.0\2.10.0\engines". But that is a far as I understand. Can someone break this down into more basic pieces.

Thanks

hap

Answer (score 1):

I have never read anything on this topic, but I guess theme engines are just some kind of renderers that provide certain styling techniques that some themes may depend on.

So... put your engine dll-s to "lib\gtk-2.0\2.10.0\engines" and your themes to "share\themes".

Then you can select a theme in "etc\gtk-2.0\gtkrc" by setting "gtk-theme-name" to the name of your theme, like `gtk-theme-name = "MS-Windows"`.

http://anirudhsasikumar.net/blog/2005.04.16.html